# OKHttp connection failed when I use sync

Tags: android, https, android-asynctask, okhttp

I got and SSLHandshakeException when I use synchronized connection to an HTTPS server. If I use asynchronized connection to same url I can't get two differentes answer:

Case 1: If I call the asynchronized request directly from main thread I got an 403 forbidden and empty response body.

Case 2: If I call the asynchronized request from a AsyncTask that had been called from main I got an 200 and the right response body that I am expecting.

So my question, why will the synchronized requested fail, and why I have to call the asynchronized request through an AsyncTask to get the expected answer?

**UPDATE**
Looks like the problem with calling synchronous request inside the AsyncTask is that the Authenticator to OKHttp client is not done setting the Authenticator, therefor I am getting the Handshake Exception.

***LAST UPDATE***
Got it to work. Refactored the posting string. From just getting the toString of a map to creating a JSONObject. Somehow, the authorization then passed and it wasn't even necessary to increased the timeout.

Comment: what is the error you got?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, the problem is making a request form the main thread.
If you read:
[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).

You will understand that you cannot make network requests from the Ui thread(since Api 11 I think).
**EDIT**

Check google page:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html. 
**EDIT 2** 
If the request is asynchronous, e.g using OKHttp async way, then the problem might come from the fact that you have a small timeout, I usually set it to 3-5 seconds(I had this problem).

Comment: Network requests should be done on an async task, not main thread - it is really wrong. You can read on google docs.

Comment: I am not sure you know about asynchronous request provided by OKHTTP library.

Comment: Nice shot. Well, the asynchronous way worked without problem. But I want it to do synch way from inside a Async Task, then the timeout hint didn't work, even setting the timeout to 1 minute din't helped.

Comment: For me the timeout worked. I will update if another thing comes to mind. Do you use certs?

Comment: Yes, using certs, and setted to just one ciphering. 

Actually, I got it to work. Refactored the way of posting.